# Connecting to ssh using sshfs visual studio code

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, remote-access

I'm trying to connect to a ssh connection so that edits to my workspace in VSCode will be reflected on the remote folder. I'm using the SSH FS extension in visual studio code. I've set up the configuration in user settings like this.

```
       "sshfs.configs": [
    {
        "label": "Linode connection",
        "root": "/",
        "host": "123.45.678.910",
        "port": 22,
        "username": "xxxx",
        "password": "yyyyy",
        "name": "abcd"
    }
]
```

When I select the "connect as workspace folder" option, I end up with this error. 
[image]

Is is something to do with filling the 'name' tag in wrong? I'm not really sure about what should go in there? If thats not it, what do I do to connect?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the password key and value and then try to connect again, VS Code will ask you for the password of remote machine each once you need.